# jsp page not working in chrome but works in firefox

Tags: html, jsp, google-chrome, mozilla

I have tested in firefox it works but in google chrome its not working. Thanks.

[image: here is the firefox inspection] 
[image: here the chrome inspect]

Comment: Can you strip it down to a minimal example?

Comment: response.setContentType("text/html"); solves the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.setContentType("text/html"); solves the problem